# Как растянуть дочерний элемент на всю высоту родителя?

Tags: css

Нужно растянуть блок с цифрой 1 на такую же высоту, как и блок, содержащий цифры 2 и 3.

Родитель блока .label (с цифрой 1) имеет такую же высоту, как и блок, содержащий цифры 2 и 3. Но сам .label с цифрой 1 имеет дефолтную высоту. Как это можно изменить?

```css
.list {
    display: flex;
}

.parent {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.label {
    background: #999;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="label">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="label">2</div>
        <div class="list">
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="label">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
}

.parent {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.label {
  background: #999;
  text-align: center;
}
.label1 {
  background: #999;
  text-align: center;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="label1">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="label">2</div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="label">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```